# Google Drive Android API tutorial issue

Tags: android, google-drive-android-api

Following [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/auth), I pasted this code into my Main Activity:

```
@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
        try {
            connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, RESOLVE_CONNECTION_REQUEST_CODE);
        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
            // Unable to resolve, message user appropriately
        }
    } else {
        GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(connectionResult.getErrorCode(), this, 0).show();
    }
}
```

I end up having to import a buncha libraries, but I still can't fix this error:

```
RESOLVE_CONNECTION_REQUEST_CODE cannot be resolved to a variable
```

any ideas??? I can't figure out which library contains this constant...

Answer (score 12):

Turns out when the tutorial specifies to start with an android project, they mean a Google Drive android project, which has different imports and class definitions, which aren't made clear from the tutorial. They actually give some starter code for a Google Drive android project, but they mislabeled it as just a "Android Quickstart" so I assumed it was no different from any other android project.

[image]

Here's where the link goes: [Google Drive Android Quickstart](https://github.com/googledrive/android-quickstart), and the tutorial makes alot more sense if you use this code as a reference.

If anybody is curious what the fix to the original issue is, the constant should actually be
`REQUEST_CODE_RESOLUTION`, but again, there are alot more changes so just use the [Google Drive Android Quickstart](https://github.com/googledrive/android-quickstart)